# Cannot modify MP3 metadata

Tags: windows-7, windows, mp3, windows-media-player

I cannot change the metadata on some MP3s in Windows 7. I change the information, but it is lost later. Also, in Windows Media Player, I cannot see the tagging information and I cannot seek in the files. What is the problem?

Comment: is there any "superuser"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, some other program is changing it later.  You could try making the file read-only, but that may not stop it.  Also, you could modify the [ACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374872.aspx) (Access Control List) so that you literally have no write access to the file (which is a stronger kind of "read only" than just setting the read-only bit in the file properties).

Comment: is this approach is on file/folder properties..but it dont work for me!